# Does this sentence "You should look through under the desk." make sense?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

Does this sentence

> You should look through under the desk.

make sense?
Like these sentences:

- You should look through on the desk.
- You should look through the room.

Comment: I have rolled your question back. Please do not edit your question to add a different question to it.

Answer (score 1):

I can make some sense. But on their own they are not very clear.

"[Look through](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/look_through)" can act as a phrasal verb (meaning search), so I'd assume that the object of "look through" has been omitted. "Look through it under the desk" would probably be better. The difference with search is that "Look through" always takes an object - the thing being searched. So while we can say "search for a pen" we can't say "look through for a pen" (though "look through your room for a pen" is correct).

In the second example I would interpret "under the stars" as a noun phrase, which is possible but not very natural. Why not say "I like reading under the stars"

Semantically both sentences are odd: You are more likely to look through something sitting at your desk rather than under it. And a starry night is too dark for reading.

Answer (score 0):

"Through" and "under" are adverbs which modify the verb "look" telling someone exactly where they should look. If I look "through" the desk, I will open drawers and examine everything, perhaps on the top of the desk as well. Looking "under" the desk is a different place. If told to look under the desk, I would examine the floor underneath it. Putting two different adverbs which mean completely different places does not make sense in English.

"I like under the stars for reading" isn't terribly bad. In fact, I think it is somewhat poetic, but if you want people to understand you, put the adverb phrase "under the stars" with the verb "to read" as in "I like to read under the stars".